# Restful API query url changes semicolon(;) to ampersand (&) atomatically

Tags: rest, restful-url

I am triggering a Rest query that contains `;` separator in the url, but it automatically changes to `&` that causing rest fails. I tried in DHC client also, same issue. What would be the root cause? Can anyone help me?

Actual query:

```
http://localhost:8080/abc/test?q=type;EQUALS;sample
```

Changed query:

```
http://localhost:8080/abc/test?q=type&EQUALS&sample
```

Comment: Who is changing this? Your browser? What client do you use? How?

Comment: my DHC client changes. Don't know why.

Comment: What happens if you just use the URL in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the DHC client tool for the url input there are some restriction for the url permitted character. I think it accept the url on the basis of the collection of the character. Here is the character list :-

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-&?=';
```

Other framework and CMS also support only for those parameter. and if any one add the character other then this it converted into its default permitted url character.